# ROI labeller for training images for R-CNN image analysis

Tags: matlab, image-processing, tensorflow, theano, conv-neural-network

I have a set of ground truth data images with multiple ROIs which I will use to train an R-CNN for image analysis.  To create the training set I need to manually identify and label the ROIs (yeah, won't that be fun).  What good applications can I use for this other than Matlab's Training Image Labeller?  Is there any app out there which would allow me to identify ROIs and then label them and output a file with the ROI coords and labels?  Output format doesn't matter but JSON would be ideal.

OR, if no such application exists outside Matlab, is there an application which could quickly / easily extract the ROIs into a separate image file which I could label?  When they created training datasets like CIFAR-10, what did they use?

Comment: any udpate on this? what path did you take?